# Edit question title or make new question?

Tags: discussion, editing, question-titles

I had a question that I asked about owncloud server 12.04. I recently had the person that answered the question review it and make sure it's relevant to 14.04.1. Should I edit this question, [Installing Owncloud server on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362326/owncloud-server-on-ubuntu-12-04), to say 12.04/14.04.1 or should I make a new question and copy paste the info over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions are, in essence, timeless.

Normally the only things that has to take care of the context (or version of Ubuntu) are answers themself. They are more fluid that questions.

Which comes to the following point, **questions do not change with each release of Ubuntu** (there are some that are very specific to a version, but normally are bugs), and editing every question to change/remove those references each time there's a release is a fools task; answers on the other hand can/should.

Instead of trying to force the version of Ubuntu in your title, make your question title reflect the specific problem as expressed in your question. I already edited your title to what you are actually asking about (the original title wasn't descriptive at all) so it should be better now.

There are some excellent guides on [how to write a good title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/213575) as well as some common pitfalls that users trip with.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that should take care of it. I appreciate the info too.

Answer (score 1):

A slight point of contention is that some problems really do change with the version they're based on so their question is best left being version specific. If part of an edit requires you to remove or replace a huge amount of that context, it's probably a bum edit and you should probably start a new question.

A good indication (though not always a limiting factor) for this is a pile of answers that don't work because everything they refer to has changed.

This is not one of those circumstances. I've actually been able to make the answer even more version-generic, which is always nice.