# Remove EOL tags

Tags: support, tags

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases some of tags are out of date such as `13.10`, `13.04` and more. and according to [@rinzwind's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521805/12-04-red-circle-icon-in-top-right-corner-cant-remove#comment709732_521805)

> We only support official Ubuntu releases (that are not end of life).

then why we still need to use that tags?

Comment: That a release is end of life does not mean the question asked during the period it was NOT end of life becomes invalid. Only new ones are invalid and even then: sometimes I just comment and not flag (when I realize it might be a problem not specific to the release).

Comment: As I said in [my other post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/11932/169736) remove information that isn't relevant anymore. If the tag isn't relevant by todays standards it will prevent people asking new questions because "that's not the version of Ubuntu I'm using"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do we keep the tag? Because we still have  questions that were asked for end-of-life releases when they were alive.

That sort of leads onto why we keep the questions. There are a few schools of thought here:

- Delete them all because they're no longer applicable
- Delete the tags, stripping an amount of meta-data from all those questions
- Leave it as it is and get on with life.

I make no secret that I'm firmly in the third category. We certainly don't need to keep every question ever asked but I strongly object to nuking things, even if they technically don't apply any more. They serve as  good, searchable record of approaches to fixing things.

More than anything, Stack Exchange built on the premise of making the internet a better place and I simply don't see how deleting a large portion of it every 6 months is going to do that.

And it does make new off-topic questions easy to spot.

Comment: I am in the "Leave it as it is and get on with life." camp. I am also in the "Moderating should be done on things you see happen on the 1st page" camp.

Comment: Yes indeed. The last thing we need is more busywork. There are tons of things to do without all this.